# Problems with PHP bitwise & operator

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Alright, so i have this code:

```
<?php
$p = 65536;
$p2 = 33554432;
if($p & $p2){
echo "True";
}else{
echo "False";
}
?>
```

Alright so if i put the numbers in the script the output is "False", but when i use $_GET,$_POST, etc it returns "True" even if i put the numbers in quotes.

whats the problem?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This has to be the worst (while still being accurate) title :)

Comment: Can you please clarify the expected input/output, and the unexpected result you're seeing?  I'm not sure if your problem is with the code example you provided, or with a different version of the script involving `$_GET`

Comment: Where are you using $_GET or $_POST? Have you verified that they have the values you think they do?

Answer (score 3):

Elements of `$_GET` and `$_POST` are strings. If you read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), it converts each character into its ordinal position, hits them with the bitwise operator, and converts back to a character.

You should call [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) on the values first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast them to int, or you are doing `&` with two strings.

```
$p = (int)$_GET['p'];
$p2 = (int)$_GET['p2'];
if ($p & $p2) {
  // ...
```